# make options section round using css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i have this  select input that i want to make round 
[need this area to be round](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05cOx.png)

here is a fiddle with what i have done 
https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/2zu3m614/4/

```
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

i need to make the option part round is it even possible.

Comment: It is currently not possible by usual way. You can use some kind of [fake select](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp).

Answer (score 0):

As of now there isn't css styling for the option elements.

However there is a Jquery plugin for this:

http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/